# Prevent upvote model from being called for every comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance, model

I have three models: User, Comment and Upvote. User-to-Comment has a one-to-many relation, Comment-to-Upvote has a one-to-many relation and User-to-Upvote has a one-to-many relation.

I want to do something similar to the upvoting done on Stackoverflow. So when you upvote/downvote the arrow will highlight and remain highlighted even if you refresh the page or come back to the page days/weeks later.

Currently I am doing this:

```
<% if Upvote.voted?(@user.id, comment.id) %>
  <%= link_to '^', ... style: 'color: orange;'%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to '^', ... style: 'color:black;'%>
<% end %>
```

where the `voted?` method looks like this:

```
  def self.voted?(user_id, comment_id)
    find_by(comment_id: comment_id, user_id: user_id).present?
  end
```

So if I have 10 comments on a page, this will load an upvote from my database 10 times, just to check if it exist!

There has to be a better way to go about doing this, but I think my brain stopped working, so I can't think of any.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling voted on the `Upvote` class. If you think about the action of voting, this isn't something that the `comment` does, but rather the `user`. I would move the method into the `User` class.

Comment: On a side note, instead of doing `find_by().present?`, it might be better to do `exists?()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have properly set relations

```
# user.rb
class User
  has_many :upvotes
end
```

we can load comments, current user and his upvotes:

```
# comments_controller.rb
def index
  @comments = Comment.limit(10)
  @user = current_user
  user_upvotes_for_comments = current_user.upvotes.where(comment_id: @comments.map(&:id))
  @upvoted_comments_ids = user_upvotes_for_comments.pluck(:comment_id)
end
```

And then change `if` condition in view:

```
# index.html.erb
<% if @upvoted_comments_ids.include?(comment.id) %>
  <%= link_to '^', ... style: 'color: orange;'%>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to '^', ... style: 'color:black;'%>
<% end %>
```

It will require only 2 DB queries. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you also use a "has_many through" association, and define user --> upvotes --> comments, you can then perform the same as this with a join and a single hit to the db.

Comment: You could also save yourself a map and reduce the size of the database query by doing `@comments = Comment.limit(10).pluck(:id)`

Comment: @williamcodes comments objects are required to be displayed on the page, so we can't use `pluck`

Answer (score 4):

We can do it the following way if you want it to be handled by a single query.

Lets make sure the relations are proper

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_many :upvotes
end

# comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :upvotes
end

# upvote.rb
class Upvote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end
```

Then in the controller

```
def index
  current_user = User.first # current_user may come from devise or any authentication logic you have.
  @comments = Comment.select('comments.*, upvotes.id as upvote').joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN upvotes ON comments.id = upvotes.comment_id AND upvotes.user_id = #{current_user.id}")
end
```

And in view

```
# index.html.erb
<% @comment.each do |comment| %>
  <% link_color =  comment.upvote ? 'orange' : 'black' %>
  <%= link_to '^', ...style: "color: #{link_color}" %>
<% end %>
# And all of your logics ;)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're limited to `N` comments per page then you can probably do this in two queries using the `limit` and `offset` methods to return the 1st, 2nd, ... `ith` set of `N` comments for the `ith` page, something like (syntax may be off, Ruby isn't my primary language)

```
comment_ids = 
    Comments.select("comment_id")
            .where(user_id: user_id)
            .order(post_date/comment_id/whatever)
            .offset(per_page * (page_number - 1)) // assumes 1-based page index
            .limit(per_page)
```

This gives you a list of `comment_ids` which you can use to query Upvote:

```
upvoted_comments = 
    Upvotes.select("comment_id")
           .where(user_id: user_id, comment_id: comment_ids)
```

If you're sorting the `comment_ids` by a column that also exists in `Upvote` (e.g. if you're sorting by `comment_id`) then you can replace the `Upvote` set query with a range query.

Put `upvoted_comments` in a hash and you're good to go - if the `comment_id` is in the hash then it's been upvoted, else not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will avoid excess queries in this state but maybe you could include the upvotes when you fetch comments:

```
@comments = Comment.includes(:upvotes).where(foo: 'bar').limit(10)
```

Then in the view:

```
<%=
  link_color =  comment.upvotes.map(&:user_id).include?(@user.id) ? 'orange' : 'red'
  link_to '^', ...style: "color: #{link_color}"
%>
```

Comment: I would be in the same situation hitting my DB 10 times, querying for the existence of an object.

Comment: I liked your change to the view, it's cleaner than what I had.

Comment: I updated it, but I'm wondering if it will cause increased queries still.

Comment: How about 

`link_color = comment.upvotes.detect{|upvote| upvote.user_id == @user.id} ? 'orange' : 'red'`